# Data Flow Task is no longer available in Visual Studio 2012 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, dataflowtask

I've worked on an SSIS project in Visual Studio 2012 for a while. Recently, when I tried to modify it, the following error message shown on a "Data Flow Task":

`"The task has failed to load"`. And I cannot find "Data Flow Task" item in SSIS Toolbox. When I tried to add a Data Flow Task on the canvas, got the error message below:

> Registration information about the Data Flow task could not be
>   retrieved. Confirm that this task is installed properly on the
>   computer.  ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: TaskHost
>   "{5918251B-2970-45A4-AB5F-01C3C588FE5A}"' is not installed correctly
>   on this computer. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design)

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated very much!

- Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise;
- SQL Server: SQL Server 2012;
- SQL Server Data Tools: 11.1.20627.00
- Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Comment: My gut thought would be that SSDT has been corrupted. 5918251B-2970-45A4-AB5F-01C3C588FE5A does correctly associate to a [2012 installation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.mainpipeclass(v=sql.110).aspx) so version compatibility looks good

Comment: Thank for reply. So you recommendation would be to reinstall SSDT?

Comment: Yep. Uninstall SSDT-BI first, and then re-install it.

Comment: Uninstalled the current one, and reinstalled the new one, and everything back to norm. Thanks all!